# Outbound adapter attempting to send message after client is already disconnected

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration to process data and then return a response. I have inbound adapter and outbound adapters setup with a few channels to handle the initial ACK and process the data and return a response to the client.

When the client disconnects we trigger an additional process that runs over all the data they had since in our database.

The issue is when the client sends data and we start processing it and then the client disconnects, the outbound adapter(?) attempts to send the response of that process back to the client. This causes an exception and breaks the flow of that additional process we kicked off after they disconnected.

Running this on my local machine it runs fine. When this is deployed to **AWS Elastic Beanstalk** on a **Amazon Linux 2** instance running **Corretto 11** it fails with the error below.

I am not sure if there is a way to check that the client is still connected before attempting to send. I tried using the error-channel but it does not catch it. I am quite new with Spring Integration so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Error log (replaced the client IP with XXXX):

```
Nov 17 16:19:38 ip-172-31-40-195 web: 2020-11-17 16:19:38.985  INFO 31923 --- [pool-4-thread-2] c.o.v.service.DefaultVoiceDataProcessor  : Client XXXXXXX disconnected.
Nov 17 16:19:38 ip-172-31-40-195 web: 2020-11-17 16:19:38.986  WARN 31923 --- [pool-4-thread-2] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : Failed to publish TcpConnectionCloseEvent [source=TcpNetConnection:XXXXXX], [factory=serverConnectionFactory, connectionId=XXXXXX] **CLOSED**:null
Nov 17 16:19:39 ip-172-31-40-195 web: 2020-11-17 16:19:39.001 ERROR 31923 --- [pool-4-thread-2] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler    : Error sending message
Nov 17 16:19:39 ip-172-31-40-195 web: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Send Failed; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer (Write failed)
Nov 17 16:19:39 ip-172-31-40-195 web: at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.send(TcpNetConnection.java:118) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
Nov 17 16:19:39 ip-172-31-40-195 web: at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler.handleMessageAsServer(TcpSendingMessageHandler.java:119) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
Nov 17 16:19:39 ip-172-31-40-195 web: at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(TcpSendingMessageHandler.java:103) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
Nov 17 16:19:39 ip-172-31-40-195 web: at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:62) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
Nov 17 16:19:39 ip-172-31-40-195 web: at org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper.handleRequestMessage(ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper.java:58) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:5.3.2.RELEASE]
```

Adapter Config setup:

```
    @Bean
    fun serverConnectionFactory(byteArrayCrlfSerializer: ByteArrayCrLfSerializer): AbstractServerConnectionFactory =
            TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(port).apply {
                deserializer = byteArrayCrlfSerializer
                soSendBufferSize = MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE + CLRF_SIZE
                soReceiveBufferSize = MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE + CLRF_SIZE

            }

    @Bean
    fun inboundAdapter(serverConnectionFactory: AbstractServerConnectionFactory) =
            TcpReceivingChannelAdapter().apply {
                setConnectionFactory(serverConnectionFactory)
                setOutputChannelName("sendAcknowledgement")
            }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sendResponse")
    fun outboundAdapter(serverConnectionFactory: AbstractServerConnectionFactory) =
            TcpSendingMessageHandler().apply {
                setConnectionFactory(serverConnectionFactory)
            }


    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "sendResponse", errorChannel = "outboundErrorChannel")
    interface OutboundMessageGateway {
        @Throws(MessagingException::class)
        fun send(@Payload message: String, @Header(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID) connectionId: String)
    }
```

TCP Message Endpoint:

```
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sendAcknowledgement", outputChannel = "doProcessing")
    fun initialAck(message: Message<ByteArray>): Message<ByteArray> {
        gateway.send("ACK", message.headers[IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID].toString())
        return message
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "doProcessing", outputChannel = "sendResponse")
    fun process(message: Message<ByteArray>, @Header(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID) connectionId: String): String? {
        /*** our process logic here ***/
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outboundErrorChannel")
    fun handleError(message: MessagingException) {
        log.error("error: %s", message)
    }

    override fun onApplicationEvent(event: TcpConnectionEvent) {
        when (event) {
            is TcpConnectionOpenEvent -> {
                log.debug { "${event.connectionId} is attempting to connect" }
            }
            is TcpConnectionCloseEvent -> {
                /*** kick off additional process here ***/
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `@ServiceActivator` for that your `TcpSendingMessageHandler` can be configured with the `Advice`:

```
/**
 * Specify a "chain" of {@code Advice} beans that will "wrap" the message handler.
 * Only the handler is advised, not the downstream flow.
 * @return the advice chain.
 */
String[] adviceChain() default { };
```

Where you can choose one of the out-of-the-box implementation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain

But probably the best for you is an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`, so you will be able to catch an exception and do something with that without breaking the whole flow before.

Comment: Thanks for the response Artem. I went ahead and read through the link and tried to use the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` but I am not sure how I can use this with checking to ensure that the client is still connected. I suppose I am just not understanding it still.

Comment: There is no way to check if client is connected before calling the send. What I suggest is to `try...catch` an exception via that `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` and do something using its `failureChannel` etc.